# Regex that iteratively matches all strings that begin with one string and end with another

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall

I'm trying to strip a string of all sequences that begin with a string "GUGU" and and end with something like "AGAG". The closest I've gotten is

```
replaceAll("GUGU(.*)AGAG", "")
```

but all that does is replace the "largest" instance. Meaning if there are multiple occurrences of GUGU*AGAG in a string, it only matches the outermost. So what could I do to get this to work for every instance of the regex in the string?

Answer (score 0):

Use a reluctant rather than a greedy quantifier (see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

```
String s = "hello GUGU hello AGAG hello GUGU hello AGAG";

// greedy
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("GUGU(.*)AGAG", ""));
// prints "hello "

// reluctant
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("GUGU(.*?)AGAG", ""));
// prints "hello  hello "
```